# Applying a function to a 3D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix

I have a 3D numpy.ndarray (think of an image with RGB) like

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)
'''array(
  [[[ 0,  1,  2],　[ 3,  4,  5]],
   [[ 6,  7,  8],　[ 9, 10, 11]]])'''
```

and a function that handles a list input;

```
my_sum = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2]
```

**What should I do to apply this function to each pixel?** (or each 1D element of the 2D array)

## What I have tried

### np.apply_along_axis

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424096/apply-functions-to-3d-numpy-array) is the kind of same as mine. So, I first tried it.

```
np.apply_along_axis(my_sum, 0, a.T).T #EDIT np.apply_along_axis(my_sum, -1, a) is better
```

at first, I thought this was the solution but this was too slow, because [np.apply_along_axis is not for speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849097/numpy-np-apply-along-axis-function-speed-up)

## np.vectorize

I applied np.vetorize to my_func.

```
vector_my_func = np.vectorize(my_sum)
```

However, I have no idea even on how this vectorized function can be called.

```
vector_my_func(0,1,2) 
#=> TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

vector_my_func(np.arange(3)) 
#=> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

vector_my_func(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)) 
#=> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

vector_my_func(np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)) 
#=> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I am totally at loss on how this should be done.

## EDIT

benchmark results for suggested methods. (used jupyter notebook and restarted kernel for each test)

```
a = np.ones((1000,1000,3))
my_sum = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2]
my_sum_ellipsis = lambda x: x[..., 0] + x[..., 1] + x[..., 2]
vector_my_sum = np.vectorize(my_sum, signature='(i)->()')
```

```
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(my_sum, -1, a)
#1 loop, best of 3: 3.72 s per loop

%timeit vector_my_sum(a)
#1 loop, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop

%timeit my_sum(a.transpose(2,0,1))
#100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop

%timeit my_sum_ellipsis(a)
#100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

%timeit my_sum(np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0))
#100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: `vectorize` won't help you here, sadly, as it emulates a `ufunc`, not a `gufunc`

Comment: How big is your test data for those three options?

Comment: I added what I actually did in my benchmark test.

Comment: **FOR THOSE WHO SAW THIS BENCHMARK BEFORE THIS COMMENT** The benchmark was poorly designed and did not do what I wanted them to do. Now, I believe it is mended.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be timing the creation of the `my_sum` variable

Comment: And you'd expect `moveaxis`, `transpose`, and `ellipsis` to all be the same, because they all do the same thing

Comment: Finally, `np.apply_along_axis(my_sum, 0, a.T).T` is better written `np.apply_along_axis(my_sum, -1, a)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The benchmark now does not include the creation of my_sum.

Comment: As for benchmarks for each methods, I believe they should be compared as it is right now, to clarify they are alike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to transpose the numpy array, swap the third axis to the first, and then you can apply the function directly to it:

```
my_sum(a.transpose(2,0,1))

#array([[ 3, 12],
#       [21, 30]])
```

Or rewrite the sum function as:

```
my_sum = lambda x: x[..., 0] + x[..., 1] + x[..., 2]
my_sum(a)
#array([[ 3, 12],
#       [21, 30]])
```

Comment: thanks for your answers. They both worked very well and very fast.
I added to my question, my benchmark results.

Comment: More clearly, you could do `np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0)`, reading as `move axis -1 to position 0`

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps. Thanks for sharing the timing results.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. I added the benchmark results. Although it has the same speed as transpose, it seems to be expicit and makes it better(in my sence)

Answer (score 2):

As of numpy 1.12, `vectorize` gained a `signature` argument. So you can use it as:

```
my_sum = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2]
vector_my_sum = np.vectorize(my_sum, signature='(i)->()')  # vector to scalar
vector_my_sum(a)
```

Unfortunately, this is a much slower code path than normal `vectorize`, which in 1.12 at least runs the for loop in C.

On my machine, with numpy `master`, this is only about 10% faster than `apply_along_axis` (although `apply_along_axis` changed implementation dramatically since 1.12)